# Windows Server 2008 Installing Updates for 2 days at shutdown

Tags: windows-server-2008, updates

On Friday before leaving work, I rebooted the server because of a software was removed, a UBS server in particular. At the shutdown screen, there was 15 updates. So I stick for awhile till it stayed really long at 13 of 89 updates. Because I had direct access to it, I keep it running for the whole 2 days (Saturday and Sunday) hoping it will finish install the update and a boot-up back to the login screen, only to my dismay it was still at 13 out of 89 today. I am clueless, as to what I should do now, should I wait even longer? or should I just force restart? Do appreciate if anyone experience the same thing as I did, as in "an" updates takes this long to install. I remember after getting this server, the first update took like 1 hour to complete about 140 updates in total.

Answer (score 0):

Press CTRL + ALT + DEL, see if task manager pops out, if all fails. Force-restart, there's nothing much you can do if an update hangs. There's shouldn't be any problem unless the update is a service pack or a core update. However if you're facing problem starting up, refer here:
http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbysymptom/a/windows-update-frozen.htm

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for answering this question.  One problem with external links is that they sometimes are not available or disappear.  In that case, just mention of the link in an answer isn't useful.  Could you edit your answer to add the key points from the link to make the answer more self-contained?